# opengl es efficient way to store monochrome transparent texture

Tags: opengl-es

What is the best opengl texture format to store monochrome transparent (8 bit of gray and 8 bit of alpha) texture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d imagine `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is a perfect match for what you’re describing.